# Function creates a folder but do not cd into the folder if it exists

Tags: linux, zshrc, zsh-alias

Following is the function I have added in the `.zshrc` configuration file to create a Notes folder if it does not exist and if the folder exists it has to cd to that folder.

```bash
function mnotes(){
   if [ ! -d ~/Desktop/Notes ];then
      mkdir ~/Desktop/Notes
   else
      cd ~/Desktop/Notes
}
```

I have set an alias as  follows:

```bash
alias notes=mnotes
```

After sourcing the `.zshrc` file. and typing the command notes, it will create the notes folder, but doesn't `cd` into it if the folder exists.

### Error Image while running the script when the folder is present:

[image: Error Image while running the script when the folder is present]

Comment: Please do not edit your question to include fixes posted as answers, as this action invalidates those answers.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the fi to end close the statement:

```
function mnotes(){
   if [ ! -d ~/Desktop/Notes ];then
      mkdir ~/Desktop/Notes
   else
      cd ~/Desktop/Notes
   fi
}
```